# Let R be a field. Is R[x] a field then?

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be a field. Is R[x] a field then?
I guess the answer is NO, but it doesn't come any counterexample in my mind. thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean no counterexample comes to mind? *Every* element of $R[x]$ that is not an element of $R$ is a counterexample.

Comment: For any field $\;R\;$ , the element $\;0\neq x\in R[x]\;$ has no inverse. Can you prove this?

Comment: You will find the answer in the site if you search.

Answer (score 2):

No. For degree reasons, a polynomial $P(X)$ with positive degree cannot have an inverse in $R[X]$. This means the only invertible elements in $R[X]$ are the non-zero constants.

However it is a P.I.D., and as such, has a `field of fractions`, denoted $R(X)$.

Comment: I think it is also a Euclidean domain as well.

Comment: That's true, but it's not useful for this question.

Comment: Sure, just a remark for the sake of being complete.